# Fully align bottom of text with image

Tags: html, css

I have an image with text displayed on its side. The problem is, the longer letters, (eg. 'y') go past the bottom margin, and therefore, the image isn't aligned with the full bottom of the text. Here's an image describing the problem:

[image]

How can I get the text to fully align with the image?

#### JSFiddle

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
}
img {
  height: 50px;
}
#text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Book_Hexagonal_Icon.svg/697px-Book_Hexagonal_Icon.svg.png" alt="">
<div id="text">My Texty</div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:bottom;` to the `img`:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
}
img {
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Book_Hexagonal_Icon.svg/697px-Book_Hexagonal_Icon.svg.png" alt="">
<div id="text">My Texty</div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

Inline and inline-block elements are vertically aligned to the *baseline* of the text by default.

[image: baseline]

By changing the `vertical-align` of the image to `bottom`, you're telling it to align with the `bottom` of the text, instead of the `baseline`

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox makes this easy

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
}
img {
  height: 50px;
}
#text {
  /* display: inline-block; */
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Book_Hexagonal_Icon.svg/697px-Book_Hexagonal_Icon.svg.png" alt="">
  <div id="text">My Texty</div>
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set bottom padding and vertical align for texty:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
}
img {
  height: 50px;
}
#text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Book_Hexagonal_Icon.svg/697px-Book_Hexagonal_Icon.svg.png" alt="">
<div id="text">My Texty</div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

Comment: This feels rather specific to a particular font